# Data is not get when i call web service

Tags: php, web-services, curl, file-get-contents

I am using curl for post web service call . In local i get data but when i shifted my code and web service to server i am not getting data.

When i call from rest client which is add on for firefox i get data.

when i hit through code i get following msg.

```
Error:- 1.when using curl for post it reply:- Not Found.
        2. when using file_get_contents it gives:-failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found
```

what can i do now

code:-

```
<?php

            //$request =base_webservice_url.'User/getCountries/';
            $request ='***********/User/getcountries/';

            // Get the curl session object
            $session = curl_init($request);
            // Set the POST options.
            curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,'');
            curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
            curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

            // Do the POST and then close the session
            $response = curl_exec($session);
            curl_close($session);
            $result= json_decode($response,true);
            $result1 = $result['result'];    
                print_r($response);

          ?>
```

it gives error:
failed to open stream: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
Filename: views/personal_form.php

i am using iis for hosting